# Extjs 4. combobox in grid. using index to get data

Tags: extjs, binding, combobox

I need my controller to load a grid with comboboxes.

The status field (number) in the 'equipment data' should load the status field of possible states from 'equipment states' and display these in the combobox.

When selecting a new option, the id should be saved in 'equipment data', status field. As a number.

```
// for store 'equipment'
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
?>
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "equipment_id": 1,
            "name": "screwdriver",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
}


// store 'equipmentStatus'
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
?>
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "status": "available"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "out of stock"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "status": "not available"
        }
    ]
}

// -----------------------------

Ext.define('Equipment.view.EquipmentGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.EquipmentGrid',

    title: 'Equipment manager',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        'Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing'
    ],

    initComponent: function () {

        // enable quicktips
        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

        this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
            clicksToEdit: 1
        });

        Ext.apply(this, {

                plugins: [this.cellEditing],

                // connect store to grid
                store: 'Equipments',

                    columns: [
                    {
                        header: 'Status',
                        dataIndex: 'status',
                        editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            store: 'EquipmentStatus'
                        })
                    }
                ]
    });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question clearly, but if you want to display status in the combobox and save the option you choose from the combobox with id as a number you should add two displayField and valueField in the combobox config.

```
    Ext.define('Equipment.view.EquipmentGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.EquipmentGrid',

    title: 'Equipment manager',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        'Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing'
    ],

    initComponent: function () {

        // enable quicktips
        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

        this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
            clicksToEdit: 1
        });

        Ext.apply(this, {

                plugins: [this.cellEditing],

                // connect store to grid
                store: 'Equipments',

                    columns: [
                    {
                        header: 'Status',
                        dataIndex: 'status',
                        editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            store: 'EquipmentStatus',
                            // status field will be displayed in combobox
                            displayField: 'status',
                            // id field will be the value of selected status
                            valueField: 'id'
                        })
                    }
                ]
    });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

 });
```

If it is not you wanted, please explain your question in more details. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you have understood my question. Your suggestion would be an obvious answer. But when I select my option, the field returned shows the valueField (id) instead of the displayField - screenshots: ![select](http://www.100it.be/images/ss1.jpg). ![result](http://www.100it.be/images/ss2.jpg).

Comment: Solved, I've set the valueField to 'status' as well.  Strange as this was what I did first time, which didn't work, must have been a typo or a missing field. Thanks for your time anyway, Egizeris. Everything works.